# Can someone suggest a software for video format conversion for Mac?

Tags: video, canon

I am newbie to this video world and have started using a Canon G7X to shoot video (I shoot casual video of my babies, family outings etc). Could someone help me find a good software which I can use to convert the video (codec, frame-rate, aspect ratio etc.).

Why I need such a software? Because G7X allows me to shoot 60p video and my TV (Samsung smart TV) does not play anything beyond 30p.

I also understand that I can shoot 30p video directly from camera; however, I would like to create some slo-mo videos as well.

Also, I am planning to buy a Nikon D810 this holiday; so I will be taking good amount of video.

I use MacBook pro retina (15") laptop, so, kindly suggest Mac compatible softwares.

Thank, NN

Answer (score 1):

Free: [MPEG Streamclip](http://www.squared5.com/)

Paid: [Movavi Converter](http://videoconvertermac.movavi.org)

Answer (score 1):

[FFMPEG](http://ffmpeg.org) which is like the Swiss army knife of video. If you don't know how to use command line, either try [FFMPEGX](http://freecode.com/projects/ffmpegx), or (better) [learn to use the command line](https://superuser.com/questions/13979/whats-the-best-way-to-learn-mac-os-x-command-line).

Answer (score 1):

I've used [Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr) to compress things for my AppleTV and other situations. The interface is not great, but it has some common useful presets that work well.